# Touches on a subview outside the frame of its superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Need help.

Create a menu outside the frame of superview.
`menu=[[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 100)];`

When the menu is moved to the screen, superview moves too.

```
    -(void)openMenu:(UIView *)view
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^
     {
         CGRect frame = menu.frame;
         CGRect viewFrame = view.frame; //superview

         frame.origin.y=-80;
         viewFrame.origin.y=65;

         menu.frame = frame;
         view.frame = viewFrame;

     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }];}
```

The menu has 5 buttons.

The problem is that they doesn't respond to touch events. I've read that it is necessary to replace:`hitTest:withEvent:`, but I do not understand how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you wants to touch it in animation state?

Comment: NO, after. When animation stops.

Comment: Can you explain what is your need? and what is the menu and what is the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Need to increase the window bounds. Replaced the line `view.frame` with `view.bounds`. The problem was that the touch events are not responds outside the window bounds.

Thanks all!

P.S. Sorry for my english!